# Java Implementing A Working FPS System

Tags: java, frame-rate, gravity

I am coding a "Gravity Simulator" in java, which just includes a ball that has a x and y force.

The way I'm doing it at the moment (which is not working) is the following:

Rules of the program: 4 pixels count as 1 meter. the gravity is 9.8m/s^2, so earth gravity.

in my main class I have this:

```
public int sleepMilli = 17; //the thread will sleep 17 milliseconds after every execution
public double g = 9.8; //gravity
```

then, in the main loop I have this:

```
try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread couldn't sleep.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

so. how would I go about implementing a working fps system into this "game" so it doesn't affect the movement speed of the ball?

If you want any more information provided, simply ask me to do so.

Comment: Sorry, what's [fps](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FPS)?

Comment: frames per second @Pang....

Comment: And what's a fps system?

Comment: my oral expression of a mechanism in the game that allows the program to run at different speeds without modifying the movement behaviour of an object @andih

Comment: There is at least one explanation on [What are the fundamentals of game development?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9033/32196) and there are a lot of solutions like [Introduction - The World Of Bouncing Balls](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8a_GameIntro-BouncingBalls.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common solution is make *all* your simulation methods take the amount of seconds that elapsed since the last frame as an argument. For example `public void move(float secondsElapsed)`.

Then, in that main thread, measure the time that elapsed since last frame using [`System.currentTimeMilis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()), don't assume that `Thread.sleep(17);` will sleep for exactly 17 miliseconds.

This has two advantages: 1) super easy change of desired FPS and 2) your objects will move at correct speeds even if the game FPS would drop.

Comment: so, in the main loop (while(true)) I shouldn't make the thread sleep at all? just execute as fast as possible? @kajacx

Comment: @PeterLikesCode for max FPS, sure thing. Or you could have let's say max 60, so then you would wait.

Comment: I'm going to see if I get this to work and then reply/mark this is "the" answer

Comment: I'm having some trouble with this. @kajacx So I tried to measure the elapsed time by storing the current time millis, and then subtracting the current time millis from those last millis. However, this always returns as 0.0.

Comment: Make sure you don't use integer division, because `20/1000 == 0`!. Something like `(current-previous)/1000f` would do, note the `f` detonating the float constant.

Comment: Or if computation takes less than milisecond (can happen) use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) for time in nanoseconds.

Comment: that fixed it. Thank you. I'm just looking how to do this now as I'm not really a creative person. I now have the move method taking into account the elapsed millis (not seconds) and I'd like to make it move now. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Please respond to the above :) @kajacx

Comment: @PeterLikesCode Well, this page is for single problem solving, not a tutorial on how to make whole 2D physics engine. Try googling "how to make simple 2D game with gravity" or something. Then ask questions such as "This object is accelerating twice more than expected" and add relevant code, not "How do I make moving and accelerating object", that is too broad.